# Debugging - Capture The State Of An iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, debugging

My app has a bug, which I am unable to replicate when it is run when plugged into the computer.

I see it three times a day and it is quite annoying.

**Is there any way to capture the state of the app (when not connected to the computer) and see what's going on? Kind of like what XCode does when you use a breakpoint, but somehow send the data to it (or some order tool that I am unaware of) wirelessly.**

---

UPDATE:

The app does not crash. It's just that certain UITableViewCells don't work as they should at certain times.

Comment: Put everything in a `try/catch` block, and if it `catches` anything, pop up a `notification` with some details on what it caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com/) its awesome for crashes. You should also use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/) which will give you live sessions/logs of your app. These both combined will tell you many things.

Comment: I will try out Testflight, hopefully I'll gain some insight into what's going wrong